# How to lookup data in a json file using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

Using PHP, I'm looking to get an id passed via the url and then lookup some data in a JSON file... then display the data back on the page.

I'll set up the url to be http://mytestapp.php?id=12345678 and then use;

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

to set the id variable. I then have a JSON as below;

```
{
    "ads": 
    [
        {   "id":"12345678", 
            "hirername":"Test Hirer", 
            "hirercontact":"Rob A",
            "role":"Ultra Sat Role",
            "requirements": [
                {"req":"Right to work in Australia"},
                {"req":"Live locally"}],
            "candidates": [
                {"name":"John Smith","dist":"Nunawading (23km away)","exp1":"Pizza maker at Don Domenicos for 4 years","exp2":"Bakery Assistant at Woolworths for 4 years","req":"","avail1":"Mon to Fri | Morning, Evening & Night","avail2":"","call":"0413451007"},
                {"name":"Jack Smith","dist":"Endeadvour Hills (35km away)","exp1":"Pizzaiolo (Pizza maker) at Cuor Di Pizza for 1 year","exp2":"","req":"","avail1":"Mon to Fri | Morning & Evening","avail2":"","call":"041345690"}]
        }, 

        {   "id":"12345679", 
            "hirername":"Test Hirer 2", 
            "hirercontact":"Jesse S",
            "role":"Ultra Sat Role 2",
            "requirements": [
                {"req":"Right to work in Australia"},
                {"req":"Live locally"}],
            "candidates": [
                {"name":"Jill Smith","dist":"Nunawading (23km away)","exp1":"Pizza maker at Don Domenicos for 4 years","exp2":"Bakery Assistant at Woolworths for 4 years","req":"","avail1":"Mon to Fri | Morning, Evening & Night","avail2":"","call":"0413451007"},
                {"name":"Jenny Smith","dist":"Endeadvour Hills (35km away)","exp1":"Pizzaiolo (Pizza maker) at Cuor Di Pizza for 1 year","exp2":"","req":"","avail1":"Mon to Fri | Morning & Evening","avail2":"","call":"041345690"}]
        }

    ]
}
```

Which i want to search for the id, and then be able to echo the contents of the data out.

I'm reading the JSON and decoding into an array as such;

```
    $json = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

But i'm not sure how to now read the array, find the data i want based on the id, and then pull out the data so i can display it on the page as follows;

```
Hirer: Test Hirer

Contact: Rob A 

Role: Ultra Sat Role



Requirements: 

- Right to work in Australia

- Live Locally



John Smith Nunawading (23km away) 

Pizza maker at Don Domenicos for 4 years 

Bakery Assistant at Woolworths for 4 years 

Mon to Fri | Morning, Evening & Night 

0413451007



Jack Smith Endeadvour Hills (35km away) 

Pizzaiolo (Pizza maker) at Cuor Di Pizza for 1 year 

Mon to Fri | Morning & Evening 

041345690
```

Any ideas?

Thanks Rob.

Comment: can you add how are you reading it and where are you getting the json from

Comment: I've updated. Thanks.

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: Oh yes - i've updated now. Should be valid. Thanks.

Comment: https://eval.in/454440 - example

Comment: The json you provided might be coming from some service, please modify that service so that when you pass id to that service it returns on the single object rather than multiple. This is how rest apis work

Comment: Thanks @RobbieAverill, your code works perfectly to return a single array with the data required. How do i now echo out the contents of that array? I tried echo $foundAd['id']; but it didn't seem to work?

Comment: Thanks @SusheelSingh, but i'm deliberately storing data in a JSON file, rather than creating a service that reads the data and returns a single object. (Creating a hacky app to test with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed the example from @RobbieAverill and modified to suit your needs, please check if this works.

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id']; 

    $json = file_get_contents('data.json');

    $foundAd = null;
    $json = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($json['ads'] as $ad) {
        if ($ad['id'] == $id) {
            $foundAd = $ad;
            break;
        }
    }

    echo "Hirer:".$foundAd['hirername']."<br/>";
    echo "contact:".$foundAd['hirercontact']."<br/>";
    echo "role:".$foundAd['role']."<br/><br/>";

    echo "Requirements<br/>";

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($foundAd['requirements'] as $req){
        echo "<li>".$req['req']."</li>";            
    }
    echo "</ul><br/>";

    foreach($foundAd['candidates'] as $req){
        echo $req['name']." ". $req['dist']."</br>";
        echo $req['exp1']."</br>";
        echo $req['exp1']."</br>";
        echo $req['avail1']."</br>";
        if($req['avail2']!=""){
            echo $req['avail2']."</br>";;       
        }
        echo $req['call']."</br></br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: This returns me an array with the data i want... but then how do i iterate through that array to get the values and echo them out?

Comment: where ever there is array just use foreach else directly fetch it, your should pass true in decode

Comment: Copied from my example. Nice.

Comment: you could have answered @RobbieAverill you didn't so I gave him a detailed answer and modified it also not complete copy.

Comment: Yep, good on you for answering. A credit would be nice though.

Comment: Cheers buddy, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

In your current inplementation you need to loop over all the ads objects like

```
foreach ($arr['ads'] as $ad){
    if ($ad['id'] == $id){
        //do stuff;
    }
}
```

A better implementation would be to use the value of the id as the key of the json object when you store the json. Using something like

```
$ads[id] = $yourjsonobject;
```

Then referencing would just be `$arr['ads'][id];`.

You can then use multiple foreach or if your keys are knows just use the keys to output the object you need like

```
echo $ad["hirername"];
```

Using the `foreach` loop to print the complete object:

```
foreach( $ad as $value){
    print_r($value);
}
```